# Why aren't torch.functional.sigmoid and torch.nn.functional.relu deprecated like torch.nn.functional.tanh?

Tags: pytorch, deprecated

Now when `torch.autograd.Variable` is merged with `torch.tensor` and obsolete, why did they deprecate some functions in `torch.nn.functional` but not others?  Namely, `tanh`is deprecated but not `sigmoid` or `relu`.

```
>>> torch.__version__
'1.1.0'
>>> u
tensor(2., grad_fn=<MeanBackward0>)
>>> torch.nn.functional.tanh(u)
C:\Users\mlearning\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py:1374: UserWarning: nn.functional.tanh is deprecated. Use torch.tanh instead.
  warnings.warn("nn.functional.tanh is deprecated. Use torch.tanh instead.")
tensor(0.9640, grad_fn=<TanhBackward>)   
>>> torch.nn.functional.sigmoid(u)
tensor(0.8808, grad_fn=<SigmoidBackward>)    
>>> torch.nn.functional.relu(u)
tensor(2., grad_fn=<ReluBackward0>)
```

Is there any difference between `torch.nn.functional.relu` and `torch.relu`, or I can use them interchangeably?

Comment: These kind of design choices are hard to answer. You're better off asking these on Github so that the devs see them more easily. About the usage: there should be no usage difference, but if one is deprecated and the other is not, it's best to use the latter.

Answer (score 1):

You can check [this thread](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/torch-tanh-vs-torch-nn-functional-tanh/15897) where one of the few main PyTorch designers (actually a creator) set the directive.

You can also check the reasoning behind. Also, you may propose the same for the other 2 functions.

The other should deprecate as well.